# problem with the data format of velodyne lidar

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys! Recently,I had run the velodyne lidar .when i used rviz to visualise the data stream received from the lidar ,i saw different color in different point.well,this is where my problem is:does velodyne itself produce data with color information or it is rviz that attaches the information to the velodyne raw data ? if it is the rviz,then what principle does it follow when it created the color to certain point,that is ,what does the color of point stand for?this is my first question .then i transformed the velodyne raw data into the pcl::PointCloud(pcl::PointXYZRGB) format,and broadcasted them into the same format after some processing with my program,but this time,the program warned that it can't find the rgb field .does it mean that velodyne raw data at nature doesn't own the rgb channels,so when i transform them into rgb format,some error just occured?
i can't find any useful information on internet and hope for some help here,thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141276/problem-with-the-data-format-of-velodyne-lidar/) by [keygeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/12986/keygeorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-03-18**:
A little bit of formatting would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz produces the colouring. If you expand the PointCloud display in rviz, you'll see the option to change this. IIRC it's by axis at present.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1